# Filter is breaking slick.js slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, slick.js

I've made a slider with slick.js and I'm now trying implement a filter, but it breaks my slider.

Filter's code:

```
  $("#cat1-cb").change(function(){
        if ($("#cat1-cb").is(":checked")) {
            $(".category1").show();
        }else{
            $(".category1").hide();
        }
    });
    $("#cat2-cb").change(function(){
        if ($("#cat2-cb").is(":checked")) {
            $(".category2").show();
        }else{
            $(".category2").hide();
        }
    });
    $("#cat3-cb").change(function(){
        if ($("#cat3-cb").is(":checked")) {
            $(".category3").show();
        }else{
            $(".category3").hide();
        }
    });
```

How to make filter to move elements if some of them are hidden?

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/cf353shk/9/

Comment: Slick.js has built in support for filtering. $('.filtering').slick('slickFilter', funciton () {});. You can find more about it in the documentation - http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @MladenIlić thank you!
can you please give some example ? in documentation i only found how to filter by odd/even index

Comment: Hi Dave! Slick filter is basically just wrapper round jQuery filter: http://api.jquery.com/filter/. You should have a bit more examples here. Basically, slick will hide the elements which you return from filter callback.

Comment: @MladenIlić thank you!
i will try

Comment: still can't handle it :(
can anybody give a suggestion ?

Comment: @MladenIlić can you please help ?